# Trouble removing all non digits from a string

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am trying to create a float out of this string: `4\xb1.3189125061`
I am currently using this:

```
re.sub(r'[^\d.-]+', "", "4\xb1.3189125061")
```

but this only outputs: `4.3189125061` and always deletes the number following the `\xb`.
Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: What is the *expected* output? `\xb1` is a python escape code, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown by using `ord`, "\xb1" is a single character:

```
>>> ord('\xb1')
177
>>>
```

To fix this problem, you can add an "r" in front of the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d.-]+', "", r"4\xb1.3189125061")
'41.3189125061'
>>>
```

or use `repr`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d.-]+', "", repr("4\xb1.3189125061"))
'41.3189125061'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Python sees **one** character for the `\xb1` escape code. The `1` is not a separate character:

```
>>> len('\xb1')
1
```

As such, it is not a digit, a dot or a dash, and the regular expression removes it.

You may need to figure out what meaning the `\xb1` byte has in the the original data. For example, in Latin-1, the B1 codepoint stands for the `±` character, making your value look like:

```
4 ± .3189125061
```

which may have a different meaning from what you are giving it.